# Android Studio: Basic programming for a game

Tags: java, android, imageview, jquery-animate

I recently managed to develope some arcade games with the default Java GUI editor. Now I want to try to the same on android.

I can say that I´m pretty familiar with the layouts on android and some other basic stuff, but I´m struggling to find an effective method to move objects (Images) around, like you can do it in with the "timer" for the GUI.

Some say that the timer doesn´t work that well for android, so I´m trying to find an alternative way. And thats why I´m here. I tried to use object.animate(), but that didn´t worked for me at all, because the images are not moving with the same speed for the given duration.

So, is it possible to move my objects (images) in another way?

Thanks for your help!